# Craft Commerce Upgrade Stuck

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

My installation of Craft Commerce seems stuck after purchasing the Pro license. Im getting similar errors throughout the site:

`Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'craft_xxx.xxx_commerce_customers' doesn't exist.`

I've gone ahead and updated Craft to the latest version. Commerce is still on version 2. Updating it to version 3 via the control panel doesn't work (memory limit) and updating via the console yield multiple errors:

`Applying new migrations ... error: The command "'/xxx/craft' 'migrate/all' '--no-backup' '--no-content'" failed.`

`> create table {{%commerce_lineitemstatuses}} ...Exception: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'xxx_commerce_lineitemstatuses' already exists`

Not even sure if I need to update things.. Just hoping to get the site up and running and back into development.. :) I can restore the database and leave the files in place for the recent Craft and old 2.2.22 Commerce and try to upgrade again? Would that work?

Any advice?

Comment: `Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'xxx_commerce_lineitemstatuses' already exists` - that particular error happens when an update is attempted and the database isn't nuked and restored from a pre-update attempt backup before the next update attempt is made.

Comment: K, Trying to restore but even that's been an issue. Going to restore to pre-updated Craft and Craft Commerce and then run the update script via the command line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I’m not sure exactly what caused the issue after my client purchased the Craft Commerce Pro license, it was eventually fixed by restoring the database, upgrading Craft and Craft Pro to the current versions on my local machine, pushing those changes to the dev server, and allowing the upgrade scripts to run in full on the dev server. Thanks to @Brad for pointing me in the right direction.